# Dialogflow knowledge is not returning answers

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying the knowledge feature on my Dialogflow agent. I have uploaded a list of FAQs in csv format to the Knowledge Bases and have setup the response using $Knowledge.Answer[1]. I tested using the "Try it now" on the console and saw I was getting the right answer from the FAQ but when I tested it with an iOS app I created, no answer from the FAQ is returned and it always gets to the default fallback intent. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay. I think direct iOS support for Dialogflow v2 API features is no allowed. Due to new privacy politics in the intent of not exposing client keys on client side now the authentication must be handled from Server or Cloud function, and then consumed by the device

Here are some references about it:

[How to send request from iOS (Swift) to Dialogflow V2 API without Cloud Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389400/how-to-send-request-from-ios-swift-to-dialogflow-v2-api-without-cloud-function)

[Dialogflow integration of enterprise edition v2 into the ios and andriod app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981178/dialogflow-integration-of-enterprise-edition-v2-into-the-ios-and-andriod-app)

I'm currently struggling with the same issue, if I get to something usable I'll come back and post it here

Regards