# Has anyone tried connecting to Dialogflow V2 via iOS/Swift with a node.js server?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Since migrating my Dialogflow agent to V2 from V1 (and subsequently, no longer using API.ai on the swift side), I am confused on how to move forward. Currently, I have a node.js server serving as my fulfillment web hook. Since transitioning to the new version, how am I suppose to send requests from my iOS Client -> to server -> to Dialogflow (I am aware of this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389400/how-to-send-request-from-ios-swift-to-dialogflow-v2-api-without-cloud-function))?

Also, what about the response from Dialogflow from the correct fulfillment? How do I send the response from Dialogflow agent -> to server -> to formatted for iOS? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I have looked into cloud functions with google but don't know how to integrate that with iOS. I'm looking for the iOS Client to send requests and receive responses with the fulfillment acting as the middleman between the two (also seeing that it would be handling authentication).